# How can I read in an array of mixed types from a JSON file in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, api, codable

I am currently trying to create a movie search app in Xcode and am having trouble reading in the JSON file from IMDB's API.

API Example: https://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/h/h.json

I can read in almost the entire file except for the image information ('i') which is stored as an array with a URL (string) and two optional ints for the dimensions.

```
   struct Response: Codable {
        var v: Int
        var q: String
        var d: [item]
    }
    
    struct item: Codable {
        var l: String
        var id: String
        var s: String
        var i: ??
    }
```

No matter what type I enter for 'i' the parse fails. I can't create an array with mixed types so I am confused how to continue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some custom decoding here. You can use the `nestedUnkeyedContainer` method to get the coding container for the array, and decode the array elements one by one.

Here is how you would implement `Decodable`:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
     let v: Int
     let q: String
     let d: [Item]
 }
 
struct Item: Decodable {
    let l: String
    let id: String
    let s: String
    let url: String
    let width: Int?
    let height: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case l, id, s, i
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        l = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .l)
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        s = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .s)
        var nestedContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .i)
        url = try nestedContainer.decode(String.self)
        width = try nestedContainer.decodeIfPresent(Int.self)
        height = try nestedContainer.decodeIfPresent(Int.self)
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem like you need to conform to `Encodable` so I didn't include it, but the code should be similar if you ever need to.