# Swift Codable with Different Array of Dictionary Types

Tags: arrays, json, swift, struct, codable

I've JSON data, which is an array of dictionary, wherein the first item is different from the rest of the array items.

**Sample JSON**

```
[
  {
    "totalDays": 180,
    "totalWorkingDays": 148,
    "totalWorkingHours": "1184:00:00",
    "totalWorkedHours": "985:23:10",
    "totalShortageHours": "-199:37:50",
    "avgWorkingHours": "06:39:28(83%)",
    "avgShortageHours": "01:20:31(17%)",
    "totalAbsents": 13,
    "totalLeaves": 4
  },
  {
    "attendanceDayCount": 1,
    "attendanceDate": "21-Jan-19",
    "attendanceDay": "Monday"
  },
  {
    "attendanceDayCount": 2,
    "attendanceDate": "22-Jan-19",
    "attendanceDay": "Tuesday"
  },
  {
    "attendanceDayCount": 3,
    "attendanceDate": "23-Jan-19",
    "attendanceDay": "Wednesday"
  }
]
```

I'm using Codable and my struct looks like this

```
struct DashboardSummary : Codable {
    
   var totalDays : Int?
   var totalWorkingDays : Int?
   var totalWorkingHours : String?
   var totalWorkedHours : String?
   var totalShortageHours : String?
   var avgWorkingHours : String?
   var avgShortageHours : String?
   var totalAbsents : Int?
   var totalLeaves : Int?
   
} 

struct DaySummary : Codable {

   var attendanceDayCount : Int?
   var attendanceDate : String?
   var attendanceDay : String?    

}
```

EDIT: JSON Decoding from Network request method

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   if let responseObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
     print("responseObject", responseObject)
     completion(.success(responseObject))
   }
   else {
     let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 200, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Failed to decode"])
     completion(.failure(error))
   }
 }
```

**Things I've tried**

1. I passed 'DashboardSummary' struct as codable through my network request, which did give results for the first item and of-course nil value for the rest of the array.
2. I tried *init(from decoder: Decoder)* and *func encode(to encoder: Encoder)* which unfortunately didn't work for me.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62907027/5133585

Comment: Never, never ever ignore the Decoding error and create a custom completely meaningless `NSError` instance. Add a `do - catch` block and `print` the caught `error` instance. It tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Point taken. There was no problem with @Sweeper's answer. The problem was with another struct. And scrapping custom NSError with **do-catch** point right to the actual error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a *third* struct that can represent the array, for example:

```
struct Response : Codable {
    var dashboardSummary: DashboardSummary?
    var daySummaries: [DaySummary]
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case dashboardSummary, daySummaries
    }
}
```

Then you need to implement `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` to do custom coding.

You can use an `unkeyedContainer` to decode/encode it. When decoding, you keep decoding from the container `while` the container is not `isAtEnd`.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    dashboardSummary = try container.decodeIfPresent(DashboardSummary.self)
    daySummaries = []
    while !container.isAtEnd {
        daySummaries.append(try container.decode(DaySummary.self))
    }
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
    try container.encode(dashboardSummary)
    for daySummary in daySummaries {
        try container.encode(daySummary)
    }
}
```

You can also consider making the properties let constants if you don't intend on changing them.

Comment: I made the third Struct as you instructed to manage the two types of array items. And added the *init* and *encode* from your answer. However, I'm getting a *Failed to Decode* error.
    **Error Domain= Code=200 "Failed to decode" UserInfo= NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to decode}**

Comment: @uzair I forgot to mention. You should decode `Response.self`. Did you do that? Otherwise, please edit the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I did add **Response.self** for decode. I've edited my question. Added 'JSON decode' from the network request method.